# Can I use two cells in the same column as a Y axis in Libre/Open Office?

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have data arranged as following:

[image]

What I'd like to do is create a graph that looks something like the following (which I generated with graphics software):

[image]

So, for example, to generate the first line, cell B1 is the start time and cell B4 is the value at the start time. Cell B2 is the end time and cell B3 is the value at the end time. Between them is the line. Then repeat for each column.

Is this possible? And, just as important, is it possible without restructuring how the data series is structured in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such a graph, but i assume you can't **with that cell structure**. The main problem is IMHO that there's **no common y axis** for the different data series, as in this example:

[image: graph]

To get this result, you will have to modify the plot options of the data series to continue the lines even if values are missing:

[image: plot options]

So, i fear the only option is to modify the cell structure.